# Can't pass throught login form when connect to sharepoint from internet

Tags: sharepoint-server

My Network is set as this: ISP <--> Router <--> HA proxy (centos 7) <--> sharepoint server. I configured alternate access mapping External to: http://eoffice.mydomain

In local network i cant log in sharepoint web normally, and i cant connect to sharepoint webdav too. when connect from internet, browser repeat pop up log in form endlessly, and webdav got bellow error: http://eoffice.mydomain/davwwwroot is not accessible.

I wonder what is the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a setting to enable persistent cookies on your HA proxy. In my experience endless login prompts are typically caused by a cookie issue.

This might be helpful to you:
https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/installation-steps-ha-proxy-as-reverse-proxy/2169/2

*cookie SERVERID insert nocache*

Comment: I've change configuration to enable persistent cookies as bellow:

backend sharepoint
   mode         http
   balance      roundrobin
   cookie       SERVERID insert indirect
   server sharepoint_01 10.0.240.216:80 cookie SP check

but it seem not affect.

Can you help me review the config if it is correct?

Comment: If you post it I can look. Try disabling loop back check on your farm to see if it resolves the issue. This is technique is not without drawbacks but there is ample documentation online.